# Cannot send user invitations and mails in bitrix

Tags: bitrix

I am trying to setup Bitrix Business Environment self hosted version in gcloud instance (CentOs7 - Bitrix Virtual Appliance V7.3.3) with Demo Licence.

Now i am trying to add new user via invitation. I setup mailbox. I'm getting the incoming mails in Bitrix CRM application perfectly. 
But i cannot send user invitation and emails at all. I hope it will be the problem of SMTP server setting( At administration -> Module settings -> mail shows smtp server is stopped )

How can i setup SMTP server in Bitrix ?? 
if anybody here familiar with Bitrix Please help me.

All helps are appreciated.

Comment: could you try to send emails via console? did you get it ```echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail youremail@gmail.com```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use mstmp witch pre installed in Bitrix VM. It allocated in 
/home/bitrix/.msmtprc
config something like this

```
# smtp account configuration for ******
account *******
logfile /home/bitrix/msmtp_*******.log
host smtp.office365.com
port 587
from noreply@*******
keepbcc on
auth on
user noreply@********
password *******
tls on
tls_certcheck off
timeout 15
```

Then send mails via php function mail() without any setting in administator module

Another way is to use function `custom_mail` where you can use PHPMailer 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer